# Simple, semi-function string implementation in C++

Tags: c++, strings, c++11

I have three files: the header, implementation and a test driver. This is a general purpose code review, so I would appreciate any feedback on anything from style to design to inaccuracies in my logic to optimizations.

The `String` class I've implemented is a semi-functional string in C++ (that is, all methods, except for assignment, do not modify the string, but rather produce a copy).

In particular, it seems that I should have more comments in my implementation file, but everything seems self explanatory enough.

I'm also unsure if I dislike my "new syntax" that uses an initializer list when indexing.

### String.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>

namespace LCL {
    class String {
    public:
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // constructors / destructor
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        String();
        ~String();
        String(const String &other);
        String(String &&other);
        String(const std::string &string);

        String(const char *string);

        // copies n chars from string and adds a nullterminator
        explicit String(const char *string, int n);

        explicit String(int number);

        explicit String(char character);


        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // operators
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        // assignment
        String &operator =(const String &other);
        String &operator =(String &&other);
        String &operator =(const std::string &string);
        String &operator =(const char *string);

        // string concatenation
        String operator +(const String &other) const;

        // behaves like python
        String operator *(int d) const;

        // comparison operators
        bool operator ==(const String &other) const;
        bool operator !=(const String &other) const;
        bool operator >(const String &other) const;
        bool operator <(const String &other) const;
        bool operator >=(const String &other) const;
        bool operator <=(const String &other) const;

        // access operators
        // returns '\0' for any out of range i
        // negative values access from the right
        char operator [](int i) const;

        // if v has no elements then returns an empty string
        // if v has one element then returns the same as the standard []
        //     operator, but wrapped up in a String
        // if v has two elements then returns a String with all the characters
        //     in the range [first, last).
        //     Calling with first > last is equivilent to calling with
        //         them in order and reversed afterwards.
        //     If either first or last-1 are out of range then the out of range
        //         sections are ignored. (so it is possible to get an empty
        //         string)
        //     Negative values are treated as positive values, but counted from
        //         the right. If it goes below zero now then it is cut off at
        //         index zero
        // If v has more than two elements then an empty string is returned
        //     (but don't do that... it's stupid) 
        String operator [](std::initializer_list<int> v) const;

        // overload ostream and istream operators
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& os, String& dt);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& dt);


        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // members
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        // returns index of substring or -1 if it could not be found
        // begins search at start
        // passing in an empty string will never match
        // passing in a negative start will start at 0
        int find(const String &str, int start = 0) const;

        std::vector<int> findAll(const String &str, int at_most = -1) const;

        int getLength() const;
        int getCapacity() const;

        // insert str at loc
        // throws exception for out of bounds variables
        // loc follows same rules as the [] accessor does
        String insert(int loc, const String &str) const;

        // erases in the range [start, end)
        // throws exception for out of bounds variables
        // start, end follows same rules as the [] accessor does
        String erase(int start, int end) const;

        // returns a reversed version of the string
        String reverse() const;

        // returns getLength() == 0
        bool isEmpty() const;

        // replaces at most "at_most" occurences of "replace" with "replace_with" from left to right
        // returns the new string
        // if n < 0 then all are replaced
        String replace(const String &replace, const String &replace_with, int at_most = -1) const;

        const char * const cStr() const;

    private:
        // actual string data
        char *data;

        // length not including the null terminator
        int length;

        // capacity of data (includes null terminator)
        int capacity;

        // ensures there is enough capacity to add 'extra' number of chars
        // allocates more as necessary
        void _ensureCapacity(int extra);

        void _appendChar(char c);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // constructor/destructor/assignment helpers
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        void _free(); // free data
        void _copy(const String &other);
        void _copy(const std::string &other);
        void _copy(const char * const other);
        void _move(String &&other);
    };
}
```

### String.cpp

```
#include <LCL/String.h>
#include <algorithm> // copy
#include <iostream>

namespace LCL {
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // constructors / destructor
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    String::String() {
        data = new char[1];
        data[0] = '\0';
        length = 0;
        capacity = 1;
    }

    String::~String() {
        _free();
    }

    String::String(const String &other) {
        _copy(other);
    }

    String::String(String &&other) {
        _move(std::move(other));
    }

    String::String(const std::string &string) {
        _copy(string);
    }

    String::String(const char *string) {
        _copy(string);
    }

    String::String(const char *string, int n) {
        length = n;
        capacity = n + 1;

        data = new char[capacity];
        std::copy(string, string+n, data);
        data[capacity-1] = '\0';
    }

    String::String(int number) : String() {
        if(number == 0) {
            String('0');
        } else {
            while(number > 0) {
                int digit = number % 10;
                char value = digit + '0';

                _appendChar(value);

                number /= 10;
            }
        }
        *this = reverse();
    }

    String::String(char character) : String(&character, 1) {}



    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // operators
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    String &String::operator =(const String &rhs) {
        if(data == rhs.data) return *this;
        _free();
        _copy(rhs);
    }

    String &String::operator =(String &&rhs) {
        _move(std::move(rhs));
    }

    String &String::operator =(const std::string &string) {
        _free();
        _copy(string);
    }

    String &String::operator =(const char *string) {
        if(data == string) return *this;
        _free();
        _copy(string);
    }

    String String::operator +(const String &rhs) const {
        String r = *this;
        r._ensureCapacity(rhs.length);
        std::copy(rhs.data, rhs.data + rhs.length + 1, r.data + length);
        r.length += rhs.length;
        return r;
    }

    String String::operator *(int d) const {
        String r = String();
        for(int i = 0;i < d; i++) {
            r = *this + r;
        }
        return r;
    }

    bool String::operator ==(const String &other) const {
        return !((*this) != other);
    }

    bool String::operator !=(const String &other) const {
        if(length != other.length) return true;

        // at this point we know length = other.length
        for(int i = 0;i < length; i++) {
            if(data[i] != other.data[i]) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool String::operator >(const String &other) const {
        int min_length = (length < other.length ? length : other.length);
        for(int i = 0;i < min_length; i++) {
            if(data[i] <= other.data[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool String::operator <(const String &other) const {
        int min_length = (length < other.length ? length : other.length);
        for(int i = 0;i < min_length; i++) {
            if(data[i] >= other.data[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool String::operator >=(const String &other) const {
        return !((*this) < other);
    }

    bool String::operator <=(const String &other) const {
        return !((*this) > other);
    }


    char String::operator [](int i) const {
        if(i >= length) return '\0';

        if(i < 0) i = length+i+1;
        if(i < 0) i = 0; // if it is still negative then cut it off

        return data[i];
    }

    String String::operator [](std::initializer_list<int> v) const {
        if(v.size() == 0 || v.size() > 2) return String();
        else if(v.size() == 1) {
            return String((*this)[*v.begin()]);
        } else { // must be size 2
            int start = *v.begin();
            int end = *(v.begin()+1);

            if(start < 0) start = length+start+1;
            if(start < 0) start = 0; // if it is still negative then cut it off

            if(end < 0) end = length+end+1;
            if(end < 0) end = 0; // if it is still negative then cut it off

            if(start >= length) start = length;
            if(end >= length) end = length;

            bool reverse = false;

            if(start > end) {
                reverse = true;
                std::swap(start, end);
            }

            String s(data+start, end-start);
            return (reverse ? s.reverse() : s);
        }
    }

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, String& dt) {
        dt = LCL::String();
        char c;
        while(is.get(c)) {
            if(c == '\n') return is;
            dt._appendChar(c);
        }
        return is;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& dt) {
        os << dt.data;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // members
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int String::find(const String &str, int start) const {
        if(str.isEmpty()) return -1;

        for(int i = (start < 0 ? 0 : start); i < length; i++) {
            if((*this)[i] == str[0]) {
                bool match = true;
                for(int j = 1; j < str.getLength(); j++) {
                    if((*this)[i+j] != str[j]) {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(match) return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<int> String::findAll(const String &str, int at_most) const {
        int i = 0;

        // gather a list of occurences of r to be replaced
        std::vector<int> locs;

        // condition checks that at most n occurences are replaced
        while(at_most != locs.size()) {
            i = find(str, i);
            if(i != -1) {
                locs.push_back(i);
                i += str.length;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        return locs;
    }

    int String::getLength() const {
        return length;
    }

    int String::getCapacity() const {
        return capacity;
    }

    String String::insert(int loc, const String &str) const {
        return (*this)[{0, loc}] + str + (*this)[{loc, -1}];
    }

    String String::erase(int start, int end) const {
        return (*this)[{0, start}] + (*this)[{end, -1}];
    }

    String String::reverse() const {
        String r = *this;
        for(int i = 0;i < r.length/2; i++) {
            std::swap(r.data[i], r.data[r.length-1-i]);
        }

        return r;
    }

    bool String::isEmpty() const {
        return length == 0;
    }

    String String::replace(const String &replace, const String &replace_with, int at_most) const {
        auto locs = findAll(replace, at_most);

        const int L = replace.length;
        int k = 0;
        String build;
        for(int i = 0;i < length;) {
            if(k >= locs.size()) {
                // nothing more to replace so add the rest of the unaltered
                // string back
                build = build + (*this)[{i, -1}];
                break;
            } else {
                // add to the string everything upto the location to be replaced
                // then add the 
                build = build + (*this)[{i, locs[k]}] + replace_with;

                // update index to reflect the above changed
                i = locs[k] + L;

                // move to next string to be replaced
                k++;
            }
        }

        return build;
    }

    const char * const String::cStr() const {
        return data;
    }


    void String::_ensureCapacity(int extra) {
        if(length + extra >= capacity) {
            // (length + extra + 1) gets the exact necessary new size
            // * 1.5 grows large enough to avoid lots of reallocations
            // + 5 so smaller numbers grow at a decent rate
            capacity = (length + extra + 1) * 1.5 + 5;
            char *newData = new char[capacity];
            std::copy(data, data + length + 1, newData);
            delete data;
            data = newData;
        }
    }

    void String::_appendChar(char c) {
        _ensureCapacity(1);
        data[length] = c;
        length++;
        data[length] = '\0';
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // constructor/destructor/assignment helpers
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void String::_free() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    void String::_copy(const String &other) {
        length = other.length;
        capacity = other.capacity;
        data = new char[capacity];
        std::copy(other.data, other.data + other.length + 1, data);
    }

    void String::_copy(const std::string &other) {
        length = other.length();
        capacity = other.capacity();
        data = new char[capacity];
        std::copy(other.c_str(), other.c_str() + other.length() + 1, data);
    }

    void String::_copy(const char * const other) {
        length = sizeof(other);
        capacity = length + 1;

        data = new char[capacity];
        std::copy(other, other + length, data);
    }

    void String::_move(String &&other) {
        std::swap(length, other.length);
        std::swap(capacity, other.capacity);
        std::swap(data, other.data);
    }

}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <LCL/String.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

// need a lot of iterations to be able to measure the difference properly
constexpr int TEST_ITERATIONS = 10000;

// prints how long it took from created until destruction
struct MyTimer {
    MyTimer() {
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
    ~MyTimer() {
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto diff = end - start;
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration <double, std::milli> (diff).count() << " ms\n";
    }

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start;
};

// calls func1 and func2 and tests how long they take
// outputs time taken to perform the actions.
// func1 is related to LCL::String
// func2 is related to std::string
template <typename ...Args, typename Func1, typename Func2>
void comparePerformance(const char *what_msg, Func1 func1, Func2 func2, Args... args) {
    {
        std::cout << "testing LCL::String " << what_msg << "\n";
        auto _t = MyTimer();

        for(int i = 0;i < TEST_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            func1(args...);
        }
    }
    {
        std::cout << "testing std::String " << what_msg << "\n";
        auto _t = MyTimer();

        for(int i = 0;i < TEST_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            func2(args...);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// prints if not and returns the amount not equal (which is 0 or 1).
template <typename T>
int checkEqual(const T &a, const T &b) {
    if(a != b) {
        std::cout << a << " != " << b << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Unit tests
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int errors = 0;

    LCL::String str = LCL::String("abc") + LCL::String(123) + LCL::String('!')*10;

    errors += checkEqual(str, LCL::String("abc123!!!!!!!!!!"));
    errors += checkEqual(str[1], 'b');
    errors += checkEqual(str[{1}], LCL::String("b"));
    errors += checkEqual(str[{3,6}], LCL::String("123"));
    errors += checkEqual(str[{3,3}], LCL::String(""));
    errors += checkEqual(str[{6,3}], LCL::String("321"));
    errors += checkEqual(str[{1000,3}], LCL::String("!!!!!!!!!!321"));
    errors += checkEqual(str[{-1,0}], LCL::String("!!!!!!!!!!321cba"));
    errors += checkEqual(str[{0,-1}], LCL::String("abc123!!!!!!!!!!"));

    LCL::String newStr = str.insert(0, LCL::String("@"));
    newStr = newStr.insert(1, LCL::String("[what's this?]"));

    errors += checkEqual(newStr[{0,-1}], LCL::String("@[what's this?]abc123!!!!!!!!!!"));
    errors += checkEqual(newStr.erase(2, 9).erase(6, 7), LCL::String("@[this]abc123!!!!!!!!!!"));
    errors += checkEqual(newStr.replace(LCL::String("["), LCL::String("(")).replace("]", ")"), LCL::String("@(what's this?)abc123!!!!!!!!!!"));
    errors += checkEqual(newStr.replace(LCL::String("!"), LCL::String(""), 5), LCL::String("@[what's this?]abc123!!!!!"));

    errors += checkEqual(LCL::String("abc") < LCL::String("bc"), true);
    errors += checkEqual(LCL::String("abc") <= LCL::String("abc"), true);
    errors += checkEqual(LCL::String("abc") >= LCL::String("abc"), true);
    errors += checkEqual(LCL::String("bc") > LCL::String("abc"), true);
    errors += checkEqual(LCL::String("a") > LCL::String("b"), false);

    std::cout << "\nEncountered '" << errors << "' errors.\n";

    std::cout << "test 'istream >> ' operator by entering a line-terminated string please:\n";
    std::cin >> str;

    std::cout << "you entered: " << str << "\n";




    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Benchmarks
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    std::cout << "every test iterates each operation " << TEST_ITERATIONS << " times\n\n\n";

    comparePerformance("'char *' constructor efficiency",
                        [](){auto str = LCL::String("This is a test!!!!");},
                        [](){auto str = std::string("This is a test!!!!");});

    const int LONG_STRING_SIZE = 10000;
    char LONG_STRING[LONG_STRING_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0;i < LONG_STRING_SIZE-1; i++) LONG_STRING[i] = 'a';
    LONG_STRING[LONG_STRING_SIZE-1] = '\0';
    comparePerformance("'char *' long constructor efficiency",
                        [LONG_STRING](){auto str = LCL::String(LONG_STRING);},
                        [LONG_STRING](){auto str = std::string(LONG_STRING);});

    const LCL::String LCL_String_small("small");
    const LCL::String LCL_String_long(LONG_STRING);
    const std::string STD_String_small("small");
    const std::string STD_String_long(LONG_STRING);

    comparePerformance("adding small to small",
                        [&](){auto str = LCL_String_small + LCL_String_small;},
                        [&](){auto str = STD_String_small + STD_String_small;});

    comparePerformance("adding long to long",
                        [&](){auto str = LCL_String_long + LCL_String_long;},
                        [&](){auto str = STD_String_long + STD_String_long;});

    comparePerformance("adding small to long",
                        [&](){auto str = LCL_String_small + LCL_String_long;},
                        [&](){auto str = STD_String_small + STD_String_long;});

    const LCL::String LCL_A = LCL::String("a");
    // intentionally copy std::string for fair comparison because LCL::String is semi-functional and does not modify the object
    comparePerformance("inserting single character to small at begining",
                        [&](){LCL_String_small.insert(0, LCL_A);},
                        [&]() mutable {auto f = STD_String_small; f.insert(0, "a");});

    comparePerformance("inserting single character to long at begining",
                        [&](){LCL_String_long.insert(0, LCL_A);},
                        [&]() mutable {auto f = STD_String_long; f.insert(0, "a");});

    comparePerformance("inserting long string to long at begining",
                        [&](){LCL_String_long.insert(0, LCL_String_long);},
                        [&]() mutable {auto f = STD_String_long; f.insert(0, STD_String_long);});

    comparePerformance("erase small amount from long",
                        [&](){LCL_String_long.erase(10, 20);},
                        [&]() mutable {auto f = STD_String_long; f.erase(10, 10);});

    comparePerformance("erase large amount from long",
                        [&](){LCL_String_long.erase(10, 1000);},
                        [&]() mutable {auto f = STD_String_long; f.erase(10, 990);});



    return 0;
}
```